# Issues with Composer dependencies, php.ini on Windows

Tags: php, windows, laravel, composer-php

I recently initiated a Composer project using Laravel, and have faced the following issue whenever I try to launch the server from cmd:

> "Warning:
>   require(C:\Users\Adam\learning-laravel-5\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\Adam\learning-laravel-5\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17"

To remedy this, I tried running php composer.phar update from within the project directory and got the following problem:

> "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1 
>   -laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires ext-openssl * -> the requested PHP extension openssl is missing from your system"

I opened up php from wamp and made sure that the php_openssl extension had a checkmark next to it, and made sure that the php.ini file in the same directory as the php.exe I was calling from had the `"extension=php_openssl.dll"` line was uncommented. What could possibly be causing this PHP extension to be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The commandline version of PHP usually uses a different configuration file. Make sure you edited the right file. PHP will show you which file it uses on the command line when you run `php -i` (it will print a lot of stuff and the info is at the top, you probably want `php -i | more`).

Comment: The path they gave me was the exact same one in which I already uncommented the "extension=php_openssl.dll" line

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still on the issue at hand but I was and I was looking at your answer as well as others and found out that the php.ini files that come with the php compressed folders **aren't .ini files**. Once you are done editing the ".ini" files make sure you file save as type exactly "php.ini" and set file type to all files. After this is done move the other two files to somewhere else, rerun whatever you were trying to run. Sorry if this doesn't help, but it helped me!